# Arrays manipulation and indexing

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to plot a curve defined as follows :

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
limit1 = 50
nPoints1=50
x1 = np.arange(0,limit1,1)
noise = np.asarray(np.random.randn(1,limit1))*15
y1 = x1**1.5 + noise
ts =  pd.DataFrame(y1[0],index=x1)
```

I also want to plot the confidence interval of that curve so I compute:

```
ts_avg_smooth = ts.rolling(window=50,min_periods=1).mean()
ts_std_smooth = ts.rolling(window=50,min_periods=1).std()
```

Finally I make the plot

```
fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))

ax1.plot(ts_avg_smooth)
ax1.fill_between(ts.index,ts_avg_smooth[0]+ts_std_smooth[0],ts_avg_smooth[0]-ts_std_smooth[0],alpha=0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I do not understand why I need to index my time series (use the [0]) in the following cases

```
ts =  pd.DataFrame(y1[0],index=x1)
ts_avg_smooth[0]+ts_std_smooth[0]
```

Could someone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you've created a `pandas` dataframe when you've made `ts_avg_smooth` and `ts_std_smooth`, and your values are in column `0`:

```
>>> ts_avg_smooth.head()
           0
0  -1.255492
1  -3.943411
2   1.838591
3   8.166289
4  11.074124
>>> ts_std_smooth.head()
           0
0        NaN
1   3.801292
2  10.369164
3  15.226252
4  14.702265
```

So you need to select your values in column `0`, which you can do by using `[0]` as your indexer

As for the `y1[0]`, that is needed because `y1` is a 2 dimensional array (`y1.shape` is `(1,50)`). So you need to select the first dimension, to turn it into a 1 dimensional array of your 50 values. Or, you can create it using `noise = np.asarray(np.random.randn(limit1))*15`, rather than `np.random.randn(1,limit1)`, so that it is 1 dimensional to start with.

Comment: what about the y1[0] in "ts =  pd.DataFrame(y1[0],index=x1)"